# Esper access array event propertie

Tags: esper

I want to process the following JSON message using Esper:

```
{
    "firstname":"John",
    "lastname":"Do",
    "address":[{"street":"Maplestreet","number":100,"city":"New York"}]
}
```

When the schema look like:

```
create schema Address (street string, number int, city string);
create schema Person (firstname string, lastname string, address Address[]);
```

What is the correct way to select the event properties within the array?
I have tried:

```
select address[0].street from Person
select address.street from Person
select address[0] from Person
select {address.street} as street from Person
```

but I get null values. Is the schema wrong or am I missing something?

EDIT: When I try:

```
select * from Person
```

I get the initial JSON as result

EDIT2:
This is my Jruby code:

```
address_type = {
        "street" => "string",
        "number" => "int",
        "city" => "string" 
        }

  epService.getEPAdministrator.getConfiguration.addEventType("Address", address_type)

  person_type = {
        "firstname" => "string",
        "lastname" => "string",
        "address" => "Address[]"
        "
        }
  epService.getEPAdministrator.getConfiguration.addEventType("Person", person_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the event object is not populated correctly by your application. I would suggest creates a Java class first in the same structure to test the statements. Once that works switch to the event object you used originally i.e. XML, object-array or Map or ...

Comment: Thanks. But when I use select * from Person I do get all the right output. Does that mean the event object is being populated the right way? It seems I just can't select an individual nested property.

Comment: What is the type of the object sent into the engine?

Comment: Good question. I'm a bit new to this. I have updated my question with the Jruby code I'm using. I think this is a Hash object type right?

Comment: I don't know jruby. If you have "select * from Person" and the listener receives an EventBean already you could do "eventBean.get("address[0].street")" and debug into Esper code to see what it does and how it interacts with the Jruby generated object. Perhaps Jruby doesn't make public getters available that return the array? Esper sticks with the JavaBean documented standard by default. There is a configuration option in "addEventType" to tell Esper to access public fields in that is what Jruby in the end provides.

Comment: Thanks. The object type is java.util.Map when I do a getEventType().getUnderlyingType(). When I remove the array brackets from the initial JSON message and use "address" => "Address" I can get the values using: select address.street from Person. The problem is with the array. I'm going to look into it further.

Comment: With the underlying type being Map, the engine would expect the Map to have an array-of-Maps for Address. You could try that out by sending a Map yourself. I.e. : Map oneAddress = new HashMap(); Map[] addresses = new Map[] {oneAddress}; Map person = new HashMap(); person.put("address", addresses); engine.sendEvent(person, "Person");